# Reviecing email from zoho mail server

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, zoho

iam trying to read emails from company specific generated email server, this is my code and i am not able to establish connection with server since it's a linux server.

```
 public class Testing {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         String from = "email";
         String pass = "pwd";
         String to = "toId";
         String host = "pop.zoho.com";
         String port = "995";
         Properties properties = System.getProperties();
         properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
         properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
         properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
         properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "995");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
         Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
         try {
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                 new InternetAddress(to));
             message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
             message.setText("This is actual message");
             Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
             transport.connect(host, from, pass);
             transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
             transport.close();
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
         } catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

Please do the need full help
thanks in advance

Comment: What exceptions do you have at runtime?

Comment: It's not reading the file. EOF exception.

Comment: Add the full stack trace to your post, please. What file? Your code does not contain any file reading logic.

Comment: DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: not loading file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\javamail.address.map
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "pop.zoho.com", port 110, isSSL false
S: EOF
C: QUIT
S: EOF

Comment: this was the error i am getting.

Comment: Are you getting this "error" on your local machine after running your class? Do you run your class from the command line or from some IDE? What IDE do you use? Add the stack trace to your post, and format it properly to get the faster help.

Comment: See the JavaMail FAQ for [tips on debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).